# Error Creating Bean Controller and Repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, servlets

I've problem with Spring. I have one controller that Autowires a repository but when I try to implements the method save(), I got this exception here. Can someone tell me how to deal with this exception? I try many thing but i can't solve that.

```
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaCrudRepController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'catRep'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'it.myshop.orm.repository.CategoriaRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'it.myshop.orm.repository.CategoriaRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.myshop.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>myshop-orm</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>myshop-orm</name>
  <description>JPA myShop</description>
  
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.21</version>
</dependency>
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.21</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.21</version>
    </dependency>
    
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.21</version>
    </dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.21</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.21</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.21</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.31</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
        
        
        <!-- INIZIO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ***    Dipendeza driver Mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ***    Dipendeza driver Mysql -->

        <!-- FINE -->
        <!-- *** dipendenze JDBC e driver per database  *** -->


  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Class Categoria

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categoria")
public class Categoria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name="descrizione")
    private String descrizione;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }
    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

CategoriaRepository

```
package it.myshop.orm.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import it.myshop.orm.model.Categoria;

@Repository
public interface CategoriaRepository extends CrudRepository<Categoria, Integer>{

    
    
}
```

AppConfig

```
package it.myshop.orm.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;


import it.myshop.orm.dao.ClienteService;
import it.myshop.orm.impl.ClienteServiceImpl;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("it.myshop.orm.controller")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "it.myshop.orm.web.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf", transactionManagerRef = "tmf") 
public class AppConfig {
    
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver iwv = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        iwv.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        iwv.setSuffix(".jsp");
//      iwv.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        
        return iwv;
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDbConnection() {
        
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/corso-spring-ud?serverTimezone=CET");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        
        return ds;
    }

    
    
    @Bean(name="emf")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManager() {
    
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true); 
    
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(getDbConnection());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter); 
    factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"it.myshop.orm.model"});
    
    return factory;
    
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean(name="tmf")
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        
        
        JpaTransactionManager jtm = new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManager().getObject());
        return jtm;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public ClienteService getClienteServiceImpl() {
        return new ClienteServiceImpl();
    }
```

App Initializer

```
package it.myshop.orm.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import it.myshop.orm.config.AppConfig;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to correct base packages that you specified while enabling JPA Repositories. You mentioned `basePackages = "it.myshop.orm.web.repository"` in your main class, so it scans this and all it’s child packages but your `CategoriaRepository` class is in `it.myshop.orm.repository` package. There’s no `web` in your actual Repository class but it’s there in the packages that you asked spring to scan :)

We can either remove `web` if it’s a mistake in your AppConfig class or add `it.myshop.orm.repository` to the list like below.

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"it.myshop.orm.web.repository", “it.myshop.orm.repository”}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't vote because I'm a newbie but this is the best answer! I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Integer instead of int in Categoria class

Comment: I got the same error... I think that is something in the repository that breaks the code, but I can't find that. If I remove the @Autowired catRep it works fine and the data is not added to DB but if keep it I got this exception...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your AppConfig class change `@ComponentScan("it.myshop.orm.controller")` to `@ComponentScan("it.myshop.orm")` or add `@ComponentScan("it.myshop.orm.controller", "it.myshop.orm.repository")`